# getElementsByName "Object variable or With Block Variable not set" Error

Tags: excel, vba, object, getelementsbytagname

The error I'm getting is "Object variable or With Block Variable not set " in reference to the ".click" line of the code.  I'm newer to VBA coding and I've tried various different things but I'm unable to figure it out.  Any ideas?

The point of the code is to launch a new internet explorer, navigate to a work site, click on a drop down, tab once, then click enter.  Ideally I'd like to just click the 'ok' button but I'm getting same error so I'll probably switch it if you guys can tell me what I'm doing wrong to get the error.

```
Sub GetData()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim Ele As Object

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "http://workurl"
Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

IE.document.getElementsByName("staffGroupCombo")(0).Click

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "+{TAB}"
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SendKeys "+{~}"

'Just placeholder stuff I sometimes need to copy
'Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
'Debug.Print ele.ClassName
'Debug.Print ele.tagName
'Debug.Print ele.ID
```

Comment: There's an end sub but i forgot to include it.

Comment: Add an `On Error Resume Next` then `While IE.document.getElementsByName("staffGroupCombo")(0) Is Nothing: DoEvents: Loop` and finally a `On Error Goto 0` above your line. If this fixes the problem, then your page isn't fully loaded when it hits the line. If it doesn't, then you're not selecting your element properly. Unfortunately that's about all the help I can provide without HTML code.

Comment: Sorry, that's a `Do While ...` instead of `While` __OR__ a `Wend` instead of `Loop`.

Comment: You were correct in thinking the page wasn't fully loading.  I inserted zwenn's code and the error went away.  Sadly I wasn't able to get the click function to work so I had to use send keys.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with trying to get the button to click but I tried the method I had previously alongside what you guys suggested here and it wouldn't work even though the page now fully loads.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes constructs in a single line like

```
IE.document.getElementsByName("staffGroupCombo")(0).Click
```

don't work. I don't know why.

Try this:

```
Set Ele = IE.document.getElementsByName("staffGroupCombo")
Ele(0).Click
```

If the page is not fully loaded like K.Davis write, you can insert a break after the IE says he is ready.

```
Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
```